# Motorcycle dumping coolant from tailpipe

Tags: honda, motorcycle, fuel-system, troubleshooting, mc-magna

I'm in the process of getting my 1982 Honda Magna back in running condition. I've cleaned out the carb and put in a new battery. It now runs, but dumps a TON of coolant out the tailpipe. Almost a constant stream. It blows a bit of white smoke, has trouble idling, and overheats rather quickly.

What steps should I take to diagnose and fix this issue?

Comment: Can you describe 'a ton of gas out the tailpipe'?  Is it liquid and actually dripping out?  A misfire wouldn't cause this condition.  Since the petcock is operated by vacuum you could still have a sunk float.  The gas only flows when the bike is running.  Don't turn the petcock and leave it on the prime position, if you do have a bad float needle/seat the gas will run into your intake and fill the cylinder creating a hydro lock condition.

Comment: Any additional information you can add to your question. Have you pulled the plugs and checked them?  How do you KNOW it's fuel coming out?    What Engine do you have?  They come in 500/7501100 flavors?  Anything at all will be helpful.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: @DucatiKiller Yes, it is liquid dripping out of the tailpipe. Like I said, it is pretty much a steady stream. I was simply making the assumption that one cylinder is not firing and, therefore, expelling that gas. My petcock doesn't have a prime position. Only 'on' and 'off'. I replaced all the plugs a few weeks ago. Engine is a 750.

Comment: I have a belief that it's not fuel and that it's coolant.  Could you verify?

Comment: @DucatiKiller I was actually about to comment that same thing. I think you are correct, although I'm not sure where the coolant would be coming from. What would this mean?

Comment: It would be a blown head gasket. I've literally worked on hundreds of these things in the 80's. Have never seen fuel come out as you describe. Granted, I suppose it's possible but it certainly isn't probable. This is a liquid cooled bike and a head gasket failure for a 34 year old motor seems pretty reasonable. Validate that the liquid is fuel. I believe it will be coolant.

Comment: You are right about the coolant. What steps do I need to take to verify that it is a blown gasket? How do I know which on is blown and needs replacing? @DucatiKiller

Comment: Modify your question to indicate that the liquid is in fact coolant and I'll respond to it.  There isn't enough room in the comments.  I'll share howto identify the issue using a couple of different methods.

Comment: @DucatiKiller okay

Comment: here is a link to the site chatroom.  I'm in and out of there a lot and there are plenty of other knowledgeable people if I'm not.  You can call me out by using @ducatikiller in these comments or in the chat room.  I'll get the message.  Good luck.  Hope the answer is helpful.  Feel free to follow up with more questions.   Cheers!   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can spend time identifying which cylinder is bad but in the end you need to replace both head gaskets**

If both head gaskets aren't failing the other one will fail soon. You may not know it yet but you don't want to replace just the single head gasket.  You want to do both.

If I were in your position I'd just order two new head gaskets and get on with it but I've worked on a ton of these things so I have a different outlook on getting from point A to point B.

**Identifying the bad head gasket**

- You could do a leak down test to identify the bad cylinder(s).
- You could perform a compression test to see what cylinders have poor compression and which do not.
- You could turn the engine over a few times with the starter and pull out your spark plugs to see which ones are wet and which are dry.

Here are a couple of links that may be helpful to you.

- **[What is a leak down tester and what can I do with it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/what-is-a-leak-down-tester-and-what-can-i-do-with-it)**
- **[How Many Times to Crank During a Compression Test](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22558/how-many-times-to-crank-during-a-compression-test)**

**Conclusion**

Clearly you have a bad head gasket if you have coolant coming out of your exhaust.

IMO consider replacing both head gaskets.

Get a factory manual for your bike.

**Spec**

184 +- 28 PSI with a maximum difference between any two cylinders of 57 PSI.  This from the Honda factory shop manual.